# Can I get entries related to one category from a specific site?

Tags: templating, entries, categories, relatedto, multi-site

If I can get entries in a category like this:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionSlug').relatedTo('categorySlug').all() %}`

And a entries from another site like this:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionSlug').site('siteSlug').all() %}`

Is there a way to combine them and get entries from another site in a certain category. The following isn't working for me:

`{% set entries = craft.entries.section('sectionSlug').relatedTo('categorySlug').site('siteSlug').all() %}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relations don't work with a slug. You'll need to insert an `ElementQuery` an `Element` or the ID of an `Element`

```
{% set entries = craft.entries
    .section('sectionHandle')
    .relatedTo(category)
    .site('siteHandle')
    .all() 
%}
```

However this will only work in certain cases where all category ids are the same for both sites. You'll need to to fetch the category from the other site at first if these are different

Comment: Ok, looks like I needed a better understanding of Relations. I put in the ID of the category and it worked.